# How do I convert the contents of the array from strings into non-strings?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I read-in elements from an `HTML DOM input` and save them into an array. Unfortunately, my code creates an array of `strings` as illustrated in the code below:

```
let delete00To04Am = document.getElementById("time000am400amEveryDay").value.split(',');

console.log(delete00To04Am);
```

The code above yields:

```
['1669669200000', '1669755600000']
```

It is **NOT** my intention to for the elements to be saved as strings in the array. How  do I convert the contents of the array from **strings** into **non-strings**

For clarity purposes, my desired result is:

```
console.log(delete00To04Am);

[1669669200000, 1669755600000]
```

and **NOT**:

```
['1669669200000', '1669755600000']
```

Comment: Those *"non-strings"* look like numbers. If your intension is to convert string to number there are [several ways](https://dev.to/sanchithasr/7-ways-to-convert-a-string-to-number-in-javascript-4l) to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **map** to iterate over each element and convert it to a number using **Number**

```js
const arr = ['1669669200000', '1669755600000'];
const numArr = arr.map(i => Number(i));
console.log(numArr);
```

Comment: You could just do `.map(Number)`, instead.

Comment: Yeah but I like it this way **arr.map(i => Number(i))**. As it explains what's going on.